# How to compare two files and delete the difference

Tags: bash

I have two Linux directories which are essentially backups and are kind of duplicates with minor changes, I want to compare two the files and delete the difference.

For example: I have two directories.

```
/root/backup/2022-04-15/CS2-VM (contents:file1.txt)
/root/backup/2022-04-16/CS2-VM (contents:file1.txt , file2.txt)
```

I want a way to delete file1.txt because they are duplicates, how can this be done in Linux?

Comment: Wait... you want to delete *which* `file1.txt`?

Comment: what do you mean by 'duplicate'? contents of the files are identical? or the filenames are identical? and which one do you want to delete ... the one in the `04-15` directory, the one in the `04-16` directory, or both?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `comm -12 file1 file2 | uniq`